# Django Authenticate returns None

Tags: django, authentication, nonetype

I have the following code snippet:

```
user = User(username='h@h.com',email='h@h.com')
user.set_password('pass')
user.save()
u = authenticate(username='h@h.com', password='pass') #this always returns None!!!
```

The problem is, u is always None. I've followed code samples on other stack overflow posts and have narrowed it down to the above lines.

Any ideas as to what might be happening?

Comment: do you have some custom settings?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put something like this in your settings

```
#Authentication backends
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    )
```

or if you are using userena for your accounts

```
#Authentication backends
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'userena.backends.UserenaAuthenticationBackend',
    'guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

Answer (score 9):

Interestingly enough, check_password returns True in the following:

```
eml = "4@a.com"
pw = "pass"
uname = 'w2'
user = User.objects.create_user(uname,eml,pw)
user.save()
log.debug("Password check passes?")
log.debug(user.check_password(pw)) # Logs True!!!
user = authenticate(username=uname, password=pw)
```

Comment: hii  i check with same code but still it show false 
Password check passes? 
False
signup user check  None


Internal Server Error: /register/

Comment: Thank you for this. After updating Django version, I don't know why authenticate(…) started returning `None`, but `user.check_password(…)` allowed me to build a quick work-around! 

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you create a user like this:

```
user = User.objects.create_user( username="whatever", email="whatever@some.com", password="password")
user = authenticate( username="whatever",password="password")
```

Comment: Thanks, H H H. That was my original code. I changed it back and still no glory. Let me post the code on an answer below...

Comment: -1. This is wrong. This way the password will be saved unhashed, and will not match when checked against the hashed version.

Comment: Daniel, I tested this and it was hashing the password. Whether it was a different password, I'll never know, but it was definitely hashed. My issue was I was missing the Authentication Backends setting

Answer (score 3):

In settings.py, add

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = your custom user class
```

e.g if django app name is office and custom user class is Account then

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'office.Account'
```

Answer (score 2):

`set_password` is a misleading method, it doesn't save the password on the user table. You need to call `user.save()` in order for it to work on your flow

Comment: Exactly with my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check whether user is active? If not, you only set active for user in admin panel, or set when creating user by adding the following line to user model:

```py
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I puzzled with this problem for four days, and the above answers didn't help.
The problem was that I, as you, was using the user.save() and I could not see what the problem was, but then I looked at it with debug eyes, and it turns out that if you use user.save() it messes with the hashing of the password somehow, don't ask me how I don't know. So I worked around it by using the user.create() method that Django provides, worked like a charm:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def create_user(request):
    new_user = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    if new_user.is_valid():
        user_saved = new_user.create(request.data)
        return Response('User {} created'.format(user_saved.username), 
                                           status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response('User not created', status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I used something like this, but you can do as you wish just use the user.create().

Answer (score 0):

Also check that you have the right username/password combo.  sometimes the one that is created from the createsuperuser command is different than a username you would typically use.

Answer (score 0):

As most of them suggested if we create the user's using `User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)` this will hash the raw password and store the hashed password. In-case if you you are using User model `serializers` to validate and create users, it is required to override the serializer method like this

```
class UserSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"

    # this is the method responsible for insertion of data with hashed password
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```