# Django authentication seems to always return none

Tags: python, django, authentication

Django's authenticate function seems to always be returning none, ive already checked out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663083/django-authenticate-returns-none) and updated the authentication backends in the settigns.py file.

This is the code that i am using to save the accounts being created:

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    # Getting the information from the filled in UserCreationForm
    user_form = UserCreationForm(data=request.POST)

    # If the the form is valid then save the users data to the database
    # hash the password using set_password and save the user again
    # set registered to True
    if user_form.is_valid():

        user = user_form.save()

        user.set_password(user.password)
        user.save()

        registered = True

    # Invalid form or forms - mistakes or something else?
    # Print problems to the terminal.
    # They'll also be shown to the user.
    else:
        print user_form.errors

# Not a HTTP POST, so these forms will be blank, ready for user input.
else:
    user_form = UserCreationForm()

# Render the template depending on the context.
return render_to_response(
    'contracts/register.html',
        {'user_form': user_form, 'registered': registered}, context)
```

This seems to be working, since after i create a new user on the site, the access database its linked to updates with that username and the encrypted password.

The user_from is created from UserCreationForm which is:

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username','password','first_name','last_name','email','is_staff','is_active')
```

Here is the code in my user_login method which should be grabbing the username and password from the request and authenticating the combo

```
def user_login(request):
# context for the user's request.
context = RequestContext(request)
# form = AuthenticationForm()

# If the request is a HTTP POST
if request.method == 'POST':
    # Gather the username and password provided by the user.
    # This information is obtained from the login form.
    user = request.user

    userSubmit = user.username
    passSubmit = user.password

    #username = request.POST.get['username']
    #password = request.POST.get['password']

    user = authenticate(username = userSubmit, password=passSubmit)

    #try:
    #    user = authenticate(username=userSubmit, password=passSubmit)
    #except LockedOut:
    #    messages.error(request, 'You have been locked out because of too many login attempts. Please try again in 10 minutes.')

    # If we have a User object, the details are correct.
    # If None (Python's way of representing the absence of a value), no user
    # with matching credentials was found.
    else:
        if user:
            # Is the account active? It could have been disabled.
            if user.is_active:
                # If the account is valid and active, we can log the user in.
                # We'll send the user back to the homepage.
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')

            else:
                # An inactive account was used - no logging in!
                messages.error(request, 'Your account is disabled.')

        else:
            messages.error(request, 'The credentials you entered are invalid.')
# Bad login details were provided. So we can't log the user in.
# The request is not a HTTP POST, so display the login form.
# This scenario would most likely be a HTTP GET.
# No context variables to pass to the template system, hence the
# blank dictionary object...
return render_to_response('administrative/login.html', {'form': form}, context)
```

Comment: left out that i have been using `username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']` to get the username and password from the request, ive also tried `username = request.POST.get['username']
        password = request.POST.get['password']`

Comment: Can you show the form class you use for `user_form`?

Comment: Your indentation looks off. Can you please ensure that the indentation in your file matches what is displayed?

Comment: Sorry about that, hope thats better

Comment: Using `user.password` to authenticate is never going to work, since that is the hashed password, and you need the plain-text password to authenticate. What happens when you use `request.POST['password']` instead?

Comment: `request.POST['password']` gives the same results. If go into the site as an admin and change a users info to make them staff they are able to log into the site, but only non-staff accounts seem to have this problem.